# JS redirect url to a specific page if url matches and is 404 not found

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a JS function where I need to re-direct a url to a specific page. It works fine if the url which needs to be re-directed is a valid route. But if it's invalid then it just stays on the 404 not found page. In my case, the url is going to be invalid and I would like to re-direct to a specific url

```
function redirect_url() {
    if (window.location.href == "http://localhost:5545/url/") {
    location.reload();
      let url_to = "http://localhost:5545/url2/";
      window.location.replace(url_to);
    }
  }

  redirect_url();
```

Please note that `http://localhost:5545/url/` is invalid url and re-directs to 404 not found page currently.

Comment: Doesn't really make sense. How is invalid url going to get loaded in the first place? You need to do this server side

Comment: I agree with @charlietfl. If you are using some js framework that implements routing and are referring to that, please clarify, in which case the js router probably already has an api to handle 404s